# Swift_TransportException in Laravel 5.2 mail sending

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, gmail

I am trying to send mail for my laravel app from a gmail account with **Allow less secure apps: ON** and **2-Step Verification OFF**

*.env* part for mail:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=library@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

*config/mail.php*:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => 'library@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Admin'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
'username' => env('library@gmail.com'),
'password' => env('********'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => env('MAIL_PRETEND', false),
```

First I tried using `'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION','tls')`. But got the following error message:

```
ERROR: exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected
response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1
Authentication Required. Learn more at 
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257  
z3sm16020712par.17 - gsmtp"' in
/home/shafi/Projects/Lib/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383
```

I visited https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 and found everything is at the recommended state.

After this I used `'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION','ssl')` but this time the same **ERROR**.

What should I do to fix the error? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Visit http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and sign in with your Gmail username and password. If asked, enter the letters in the distorted picture.

**Note:** If this still didn't help then retry the process couple of more times and wait then try to send the email from your Laravel apps. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Your code is fine. However, Gmail is not allowing your Laravel apps to log in to your Gmail account which is why you're experiencing the issue. In this case, please also ensure that you've allowed your Laravel apps from your Gmail account activity options and also try changing few settings from the allow less secure apps access options.

Comment: How to allow Laravel apps from Gmail account? I tried to do, but couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**: Revert your config/mail.php to original file. The config/mail.php should look like this

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => 'library@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Admin'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

**Step 2**: The .env file should be like

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=library@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=whateverisyourpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Port is **465** and not **587**

**Step 3**: Test the below code by pasting in appropriate controller function

```
\Mail::raw('This is an test e-mail', function ($message) {
    $message->to("someone@gmail.com", "someone");
    $message->subject("hi checking");
    $message->getSwiftMessage();
});
```

P.S: Never ever forget to stop and then again start the server by using `php artisan serve` every time if some change is made to .env file. If not then you may be sucked into **The Labyrinth of Time**.

Comment: Appreciate your effort.I tried, but got the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't missed anything? I test ran the above code in laravel 5.2 with two different gmail accounts and it's working.

Comment: Can you share your project repository or files related to sending mail?

Comment: No. Tried in multiple way but ends with same error.

Comment: Try to provide your code to new set of eyes. Maybe they can find what you missed out

Comment: I think I am doing everything okay as I did this before. I will try again when it's time to deploy my work on server. Till then I will work with `pretend: true`. Thanks for your care about this.

Comment: btw, I do not think the port should be different in `.env` and `mail.php`.

Comment: First preference is given to variable found in .env . if the variable is not found then default value is taken

Answer (score 0):

For me, sending mail worked by just adding the correct info in the .env file like so:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your_gmail_email
MAIL_PASSWORD=your_gmail_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Don't change anything in the mail.php file. You don't want your email credentials all over the place. The .env file was made to store all of this.

I also turned on access to "less secure apps" on that Gmail account.

And lastly, run: `php artisan config:cache`

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem previously, the root cause was I changed the mail.php file.

To send email with smtp.gmail.com, you just need to change the configuration in .env file and enable allow less secure apps. Don't change anything in the mail.php file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to take the time to read this :

https://phpnotebook.com/how-to-fix-swift_transportexception-530-in-laravel-5-7.html

Comment: URL changed : https://phpnotebook.com/how-to-fix-swift_transportexception-530-in-laravel-5-7.html

Comment: This is a true example of not to share only link answer..